# C++ list, operator == problems

Tags: c++, list, visual-studio-2012

Yeah i forgot about including header file.
I added inline bool operator== as you suggested but still bunch of troubles showed up themselves. Maybe i should stop for now but i don't want :D
By the way, getTytul() returns string.
 So here is what i get:
header:

```
#include "Pozycja.h"
#include "IZarzadzaniePozycjami.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

inline bool operator==(std::string& s, Katalog& katalog)
{
    return katalog == s;
}

class Katalog 
    : public IZarzadzaniePozycjami
{
private:
    std::string dzialTematyczny;
public:
    void ZnajdzPozycjePoTytule(std::string tytul);
    void ZnajdzPozycjePoId(int id);
    void WypiszWszystkiePozycje();
    Katalog(void);
    Katalog(std::string dzialTematyczny_);
    void DodajPozycje(Pozycja);
    std::list<Pozycja> lista;
    ~Katalog(void);
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "Katalog.h"
#include <iterator>

Katalog::Katalog(void)
{
    dzialTematyczny= "Nieznany dzial tematyczny";
}
Katalog::Katalog(std::string dzialTematyczny_):dzialTematyczny(dzialTematyczny_){}

void Katalog::DodajPozycje(Pozycja a){
    std::cout << " Dodano pozycje";
    lista.push_back(a);
}

void Katalog::ZnajdzPozycjePoTytule(std::string tytul){
    for(std::list<Pozycja>::iterator iter = lista.begin(); iter!= lista.end();++iter)
    {
        if(tytul == iter->getTytul())
        {
            //std::cout << " Mamy tytul: "<< iter->getTytul() << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
void Katalog::ZnajdzPozycjePoId(int id){
    for(std::list<Pozycja>::iterator iter = lista.begin(); iter!= lista.end();++iter)
    {
        if(id == iter->getId())
        {
            std::cout << " Mamy id: "<< iter->getId() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
void Katalog::WypiszWszystkiePozycje(){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<lista.size(); ++i)
    {
        lista.front().WypiszInfo();
    }
}

Katalog::~Katalog(void)
{
}
```

Errors:

```
 1>c:\users\komputer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\katalog.h(6): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Katalog'
    1>c:\users\komputer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\katalog.h(7): error C2805: binary 'operator ==' has too few parameters
1>c:\users\komputer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\katalog.h(8): error C2065: 'katalog' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Could you please narrow the sample to reproduce the relevant stuff.

Comment: What is the return value of getTytul(). It must return something for which the operator== is implemented (with a std::string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two immediate problems: You have not declared the `IZarzadzaniePozycjami` class anywhere. And having the equality operator in the class forces you to have an instance of the class on the left side of the comparison, and the argument on the right side.

The first you can solved by including the file where `IZarzadzaniePozycjami` is defined.

The second you can solved by adding a standalone and global helper function:

```
inline bool operator==(const std::string& s, const Katalog& katalog)
{
    return katalog == s;  // "Reverse" the arguments
}
```

Note: I made the function above `inline` so you can add it to the header file.

Comment: Could you please look at my modified thread? Still got some trouble:)

Comment: @user3184866 Place the function *after* you define the class.

Comment: error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Katalog' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @user3184866 I said you should *add* a *helper* function. You still need the old operator in the class as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first error message says that in the class definition

```
class Katalog 
    : public IZarzadzaniePozycjami
{
//...
```

the compiler knows nothing about definition of its base class `IZarzadzaniePozycjami`
Maybe you forgot to include the header with the corresponding definition.

The second error means that in the condition

```
    if(tytul == iter->getTytul())
```

where tytul has type std::string the right operand that is returned by functionj `iter->getTytul()` has no type std::string.